# Time series with ggplot2: Using days and hours from different columns

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a time series using `ggplot`, having the day and time stored in different data frame columns. How can I tell ggplot to take into account both the date and time in the plot?

My data looks like this

```
Date    Hour_min    Tair    Tflower Tbud
Day1    8:35    24,73   29,79   31,41
Day1    8:36    24,29   29,99   31,82
... ..  ..  ... ...
Day2    00:00   23,62   30,37   32,59
```

One can load a small sample of the dataset with this:

```
#Tagua <- read.table(file = "TIMESERIE_OTO32.txt", header = TRUE,dec = ",")
Tagua <- structure(
  list(
    Date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Day1", "Day2"), class = "factor"),
    Hour_min = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("8:35", "8:36"), class = "factor"),
    Tair = c(24.73, 24.29, 23.62, 24.29),
    Tflower = c(29.79, 29.99, 30.37, 29.99), 
    Tbud = c(31.41, 31.82, 32.59, 31.82)
  ),
  .Names = c("Date", "Hour_min", "Tair", "Tflower", "Tbud"),
  class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Days, hours, and 3 temperature from different parts of the flower.
I  have 1400 minutes for 2 days.

I wrote this script:

```
library(ggplot2)


ggplot(aes(x = (Hour_min), group=1), data = Tagua) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Tair, colour = "var1")) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = Tbud, colour = "var2")) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = Tflower, colour = "var3"))
```

The problem is that R plots from 00:00 to 23 (of course), without considering the days.

How can I solve this problem?

If possible, I would like to set the x-axis tick just corresponding to the hour (eg. 2:00, 3:00,...).

Comment: You'll have to create a date time variable from you day and hour columns. Assign real dates instead than "day1' to the `Date` column,  than have a look at how to create a datetime variable from the two columns (packageb`lubridate`may have some function for that)

Comment: And, if you don't care about the actual day (just that days passed) you can use `period`s instead of actual `Date`s, from the `lubridate` package as well. `period(day = 0, hours = 8, minutes = 35)`.

Also, providing a simple demo dataset would make it much easier to help you, for instance with `dput(head(Tagua))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the shortest solution, but you can run it step by step and see how it works.

```r
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

Tagua <- read.table(file = "TIMESERIE_OTO32.txt", header = TRUE, dec = ",")


Tagua_clean <- Tagua %>% 
  # Separate hours and minutes:
  separate(Hour_min, into = c("Hour", "Minute"), sep = ":") %>% 
  # Convert Day1 -> 0
  #         Day2 -> 1
  mutate(Day = as.numeric(gsub("Day", "", Date)) - 1) %>%
  # Create a Period:
  mutate(time_period = period(days = Day, hours = Hour, minutes = Minute)) %>%
  # Create a Date, using the beginning of the experiment (if you know it):
  mutate(Date = as.POSIXct("2017-01-01") + time_period) %>%
  # Option 2: Convert the time period to hours:
  mutate(Hours = as.numeric(time_period)/3600) %>%
  select(Date, Hours, Tair, Tflower, Tbud)


# Option 1: With real dates:
ggplot(aes(x = Date), data = Tagua_clean) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = Tair, colour = "var1")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Tbud, colour = "var2"))+
  geom_line(aes(y = Tflower, colour = "var3"))


# Option 2: With hours:
ggplot(aes(x = Hours), data = Tagua_clean) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = Tair, colour = "var1")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Tbud, colour = "var2"))+
  geom_line(aes(y = Tflower, colour = "var3"))
```

Update: Restart the hours to 0 every day. Here we use Dates but we customize how they are shown.

`scale_x_datetime` has the argument `date_labels` that can be set to `"%H"` to show the hour of the day or can be set to `"Day %d \n Hour: %H"` for a combination of day and hour. See `?strptime` for more format options. Another argument that can be used is `date_breaks` to specify `"1 hour"` if you want a label every hour.

```
ggplot(aes(x = Date), data = Tagua_clean) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = Tair, colour = "var1")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Tbud, colour = "var2"))+
  geom_line(aes(y = Tflower, colour = "var3")) +
  scale_x_datetime(date_labels = "Day %d \n Hour: %H")
```

[image: With Day/Hour]

Comment: thank you zeehio. It looks great and it worked really good. The only things I would like to change is in the second option, the one with hours. I would like to have a repetition as the first one 12-18-00-6... Because now it increase until more than 30. Thanks ;-)

Comment: Then the best choice you have is working with datetimes. See the Option 3 I just added to the answer.